# How can I obtain an object with the values as keys and vice versa - and with duplicate values stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**1. My task**

In the object, how can I get an array in which the corresponding keys are stored if there are duplicate values in the input object?

```
const object5 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1 };

const object6 = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 };

/**          
1. @param {object} ???
2. @returns {object} An object with the given object's values 
as keys, and keys as values. If there are duplicate values in 
the input object, the corresponding keys should be stored in 
an array.  
*/
```

**2. Tests**

console.log(swapPairs3(object5))// , { 1: ["a", "d"], 2: "b", 3: "c" };　　　　　　　　　　　　 console.log(swapPairs3(object6))// , { 1: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] };

Comment: Java <> JavaScript.  I've modified your tags accordingly.

Comment: If this is your task, did you already try anything? We are not here to complete your tasks. We are here to help out with specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the entries of the object using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const groupByValue = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [k, v]) => ((r[v] ??= []).push(k), r), {});

console.log(groupByValue({ a: 0, b: 0, c: 3, d: 1 }));
console.log(groupByValue({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }));
```

A more comprehensive version of the above solution:

```js
function groupByValue(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    r[v] = r[v] ?? [];
    r[v].push(k);
    return r;
  }, {});
}

console.log(groupByValue({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 1 }));
console.log(groupByValue({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }));
```

Documentation:
[Nullish Coalescing Operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: What does it mean at here '(r[v] ??= [])' ? can you add any comments ?

Comment: @jessieWJ It means `r[v] = r[v] ?? []`, similar to `a += 1`, where `??` is the [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

Comment: Thanks!
Also why there's  a '[]' after  ' r[v] = r[v] ?? ', What's the  logic between them?

Comment: @jessieWJ If we don't have an existing entry for a value then we assign it to an empty array `[]` and then push the value. Check the comprehensive solution for better understanding. In this case you can also replace `??` with `||`, if `??` is causing confusion.